# Best anti-spam & anti-virus solution

Tags: exchange-2010, spam, anti-virus

We are looking for the best anti-spam and anti-virus solution to protect a multi-tenented Exchange 2010 system with 500 mailboxes (upgrading to 750 soon).

We are looking at the Barracuda 400 boxes, any good?

Comment: Any question asking for "the best" anything is off topic on server fault; both shopping questions and "subjective" questions are off topic.

Comment: Having said that, I personally favour "cloud based" filtering and AV to scan stuff at the gateway, as I think there is a lot of benefits in not even allowing stuff into your organisation just to reject it, and a 3rd party cloud provider means you still can queue incoming mail if your business internet connection is offline for any reason, possibly paired with something like forefront to scan the store itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Postini:

http://www.google.com/postini/email.html

Comment: Yeah we are using this for some other email services. Its OK but not great.

Comment: Re: barracuda: http://seclists.org/nanog/2011/Apr/182